# Remove notification from status bar when app kill from background

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am facing one problem when i kill application from background.My application is closed but the notification from the status bar is still there.
How can we remove the notification from status bar when my application kill from background .
Can we get the event when user kill the application from background ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your application is killed? As far as I know, if an application is killed, the notifications go off too.

Comment: Yes i am sure. I press home button and swipe app .and when i again launch app it will open from start means like fresh app.

Comment: Swiping an app away from recents task list doesn't mean killing it I suppose. How about trying to force stop it from Settings page and see if the notifications go or not?

Answer (score 0):

try your code to remove the notification in the OnDestroy() method of your application class.

```
    class myApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        // remove notification code here
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

***NOT TESTED, BUT GIVE A TRY***

Comment: This method is not triggered .

Comment: Make sure you have added declared the Application in your manifest this way:    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/android_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.xyz.xyz.MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: Yes , i have added and remove the android:allowBackup="true" but still this method not triggered.

Comment: In this scenario i would have run a service in background which will check both {App Running in background} and {Notification Present} after a particular interval. if both case are false stop that service.

Comment: Above method doesn't call in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because notifications is not a part of your app's process. You just send it to the notification service and it shows them.

To hide notifications you should cancel it in your program before destroying.

Also android should not notify your application. It can just kill it without any callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

In onDestroy() cancel the notification